# Java Multi threaded server not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to write a multi-threaded server which should be capable of accepting multiple HTTP requests at a time.

**Server code:**

```
package test.thread.server;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class MyServer implements Runnable {
        private int serverPort = 8080;
        private ServerSocket serverSocket;
        private Thread runningThread;
        private boolean isStopped;

        public MyServer(int port){
            this.serverPort = port;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
            }

            openServerSocket();


            while(!isStopped){

                Socket clientSocket = null;

                try {
                    clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                //start a new thread for processing each request
                new Thread(new RequestHandler(clientSocket)).start();
            }

        }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        this.isStopped = true;
        try {
            this.serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
        }
    }


    private void openServerSocket(){
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Worker that handles the request:**

It reads the data from input stream and prints it. After that it should go for a 30 second sleep[represents some work which does not need CPU]. After sleep time, server will respond to client.

```
package test.thread.server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class RequestHandler implements Runnable {
    Socket clientSocket;

    static int counter = 0;

    public RequestHandler(Socket clientSocket){
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InputStream input = this.clientSocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream output = this.clientSocket.getOutputStream();


            DataInputStream inFromClient = new DataInputStream(input);
            System.out.println(new Date()+": " +Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Started : "+inFromClient.readUTF());

            Thread.sleep(30000);

            /*output.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<html><body>" +
                    "Multi-threaded Server " +
                    "</body></html>").getBytes());*/

            DataOutputStream outFromServer = new DataOutputStream(output);
            outFromServer.writeUTF("Output");
            outFromServer.flush();

            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

**HTTP Client:**

Client is not bothered about the server sleep time and will send 5 consecutive  requests.

```
package test.thread.server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
             DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
             DataInputStream inFromServer = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());


             outToServer.writeUTF("Input");
             outToServer.flush();

             String output = inFromServer.readUTF();
             System.out.println(new Date()+": "+output);
             clientSocket.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Now i am expecting the server to process the next client request when one thread goes on sleep. But unfortunately server is accepting next request only after the previous request is processed.

**Expecting o/p:**

Server should not wait for current request process to complete before printing 'Thread-X - Started : Input' for next request.

**Current o/p:**

```
Server: Wed Feb 15 18:17:06 IST 2017: Thread-1 - Started : Input
Client: Wed Feb 15 18:17:36 IST 2017: Output
Server:Wed Feb 15 18:17:36 IST 2017: Thread-2 - Started : Input
Client:Wed Feb 15 18:18:06 IST 2017: Output
Server:Wed Feb 15 18:18:06 IST 2017: Thread-3 - Started : Input
Client:Wed Feb 15 18:18:36 IST 2017: Output
Server:Wed Feb 15 18:18:43 IST 2017: Thread-4 - Started : Input
Client:Wed Feb 15 18:19:13 IST 2017: Output
Server:Wed Feb 15 18:19:13 IST 2017: Thread-5 - Started : Input
Client:Wed Feb 15 18:19:43 IST 2017: Output
```

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your client. The client only sends the next request after the previous one was answered. The `inFromServer.readUTF()` blocks until data is available, which is only the case when your server sends an actual answer.

I recommend you debug your program.

Comment: Haaaaa.... client was the culprit. I suspected my server and spend over 2 hrs debugging it. I should have started the client requests on separate threads!!!.... my bad.