# Java programming - How to send multiple simultaneous requests to a server from many clients

Tags: java

i want to implement a Java program, in order to simulate a dos attack.I have found a relevant post in Stackoverflow about a multithreaded server that should be accepting multiple HTTP requests at a time, so my question is whether i can adapt this program, in order to send the requests not from one, but from many clients. I don't have experience in multithreading programming, so please i need suggestions. I am an undergraduate student, so i want to present the simulation to an elementary level , not something advanced.Below is the link with the program i have found.
[Java multithreaded server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250548/java-multi-threaded-server-not-working-as-expected). Thanks.

Comment: You can use a HTTP Client in Java. and using multiple threads, send requests concurrently.

Comment: you could take a look at load test tools/utilities. Something like https://github.com/apache/jmeter might do what you're after.

Comment: Is it possible to design a simple test web site in Visual Studio, and "flood" this web site with http requests, using Apache JMeter?